# iptables ignores REJECT in custom chain but works in the main chain

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I configured a server with fail2ban for the smtp server. Now, fail2ban correctly bans the IPs and I can see them in the iptables chain of fail2ban. However, the kernel seems to ignore the iptables fail2ban chain REJECT rule. Instead, if I add the same rule to the INPUT chain, it works.

The output of `iptables -L -n -v` is:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
  207  8339 f2b-postfix  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443,25,587,110,995,143,993,4190
   17  2172 REJECT     all  --  *      *       141.98.11.68         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain f2b-postfix (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       141.98.11.68         0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
  207  8339 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

As you can see, the `REJECT` rule in the `f2b-postfix` chain is ignored (0 packets), and all the packets ends up in the `RETURN` rule. However, if I add the same `REJECT` rule in the `INPUT` chain, it works and rejects the packet.

To be sure I checked also the raw iptables config:

```
-A INPUT -s 141.98.11.68/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A f2b-postfix -s 141.98.11.68/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

but the two rules are identical.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't edit fail2ban things in iptables directly, that will cause problems. If you want an iptables reject for fail2ban configure that in the fail2ban configuration. Because everytime fail2ban restart it will recreate and reset the iptables configuration. How does your postfix jail looks like?

Comment: @Turdie OP did not edit the fail2ban chain. They edited the `INPUT` chain instead.

Comment: @ocirocir please post the output of the `iptables-save` command.